# add a vertical space constraint programmatically between status bar and uiimageview

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

i m trying to make it work for both old and new devices iPhone 4s and 5s. on both devices it not showing vertical space constraint between status bar and image view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

if(result.height == 480)
{
 baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
}

if(result.height == 568)

{
    baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 460));
if(result.height == 480)
{

    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"newone.png"] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];

    UIImage *picture = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:picture];
}
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 548));

if(result.height == 568)

{

            [[UIImage imageNamed:@"newone.png"] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 548)];
    UIImage *picture = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:picture];


    //[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                               //constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-190-[picture]-280-|"
                               //options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                              // metrics:nil
                              // views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(picture)]];

  }

    [self.view addSubview:baseView];
```

Any ideas how to show vertical space constraint programmatically between status bar image view.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your "image view" is the root view (i.e., `self.view`) with a colored background. In iOS 7, the root view is full-screen and underlaps the status bar.

I recommend setting the `baseView`'s background color instead. Then pin the `baseView` to the `top layout guide` using Auto Layout.

Also, rather than fetching the screen size and comparing the dimensions against magic numbers, use Auto Layout to position the `baseView`.